# Unplugged laptop without the battery in

Tags: motherboard

I have had an Alienware 14 laptop for 3 years now. For the past year, because the battery died due to some other reason, I'd taken it out and have been using my laptop ever since by connecting it directly to electricity with its power cord.

Today while my laptop was on, the cord got accidentally unplugged and obviously it shut off. But after reconnecting the cord, it didn't turn back on anymore. The cord itself is similar to other dell products, it has a stripe around it that lights up in blue whenever connected to a power supply. But that was off after the incident. I disconnected the cord from my laptop, unplugged it from electricity and plugged it back again, its lights came back, but the moment I connected it to the laptop, they went dark while the laptop still didn't react at all when I hit the power button.

I tried once holding the power button while my laptop wasn't connected to electricity. And plugging it again but to no avail

Please help me, what's the problem? Has my mother board burned out?

I tried with a different charger, no use, still my laptop doesn't turn on

I've been told my mother board must be broken since there was no battery inside to take the hit instead, is there a connection to it?

Comment: So when you plug the power adapter into the wall, a blue light on it comes on and when you plug the other end into the laptop the blue light goes out? you said you tried with a "different charger"but the charging circuit is inside your laptop. the power adapter that comes with laptops are just power supplies. And another power adapter does no difference? Is the other power adapter from a similar Alianware and are yo sure the power output rating is the same?

Comment: Its pretty hard to say, but this *shouldn't* cause most laptops to burn out. And your battery typically does not act as a buffer for power input.

Answer (score 0):

It would be impossible to give a solid solution without testing. That is something you or someone needs to do there physically. What you need to do is test your power adapters output with a power meter (sometimes called multi-tester) and see if it is putting out the proper voltage. That is the only way you can be sure without spending money on a new one and it not being the cure.

From the sound of the blue light going out, I would suspect some caps in the PSU went which is not unheard of, or voltage regulator could have blown. There could be a short somewhere in the laptop but sound like when you hit the button that the power adapter itself just dumps on you. Get it tested. Those things don't last forever especially since so much is stuffed into such a small space. They don't generally have the longevity and durability of a pc power-supply.